# An example of a closed cone whose image under a linear map is not closed?

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-geometry, convex-cone

I need a very simple example of a closed cone $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A(K)$ is not closed where $A:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear map.

The simplest ones I've come across are where $A$ is from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, but is there one from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^1$? An example of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ is this: the projection of the proper cone $K=\{(x,y,z):y^2\leq xz,z\geq 0\}$ onto the $(x,y)$-plane is not a proper cone (not proper because the projection is not closed).

(Definition of cone $K$: if $x\in K$ then $\lambda x\in K, \lambda \geq 0$ and $x+y\in K$ for all $x,y \in K$.)

Comment: It is worth to mention that you are actually meaning closed *convex* cones. Also, can you give the example $\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2$? Maybe it is helpful in order to find the other one.

Comment: It's not necessary that $K$ be convex. Although largely a lot of useful theorems are based on the fact that $K$ is a proper cone (closed, pointed, convex, solid). The question is edited to give the example.

Comment: $x,y\in K\to x+y\in K$ does imply convexity for cones.

Comment: You are right. Cones are convex by definition. But it is the closedness that I'm concerned with.

Comment: No, your definition is for a convex cone. Drop the $x+y$ requirement and you still have a valid cone, albeit a possibly non-convex one.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Yes, what I meant was that the cone defined above is convex by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no example for $\Bbb R^d\to\Bbb R,d\in\Bbb N$.

*Proof*.

Let $K$ be a closed (convex) cones in $\Bbb R^d$ and $A:\Bbb R^d\to\Bbb R$ a linear map. Let $x_n\in AK\subset\Bbb R$ be a convergent sequence in $AK$. In order to show that $AK$ is closed, we have to prove that $\lim x_n\in AK$.

If $x_n\to0$, then the limit is obviously already in $AK$, since $0=A0\in AK$. Hence we assume that $x_n\to x\not=0$. Therefore, we can assume that w.l.o.g. all $x_n\in\Bbb R$ are non-zero and have the same sign. Especially, this implies $x_n/x_m>0$ for all $n,m\in\Bbb N$.

Choose some non-zero $y_0\in K$ with $Ay_0=x_0$ and define $y_n:=y_0\cdot x_n/x_0$. Since, $x_n/x_0>0$, we have $y_n\in K$. Next, we see

$$\|y_n-y_m\|=\left\|y_0\frac{x_n}{x_0}-y_0\frac{x_m}{x_0}\right\|=\frac{\|y_0\|}{|x_0|}\cdot|x_n-x_m|.$$

So, because $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, $y_n$ must be one too. This means $y_n\to  y$ for some $y\in K$. Note that

$$Ay_n=A\left(y_0\cdot \frac{x_n}{x_0}\right)=\frac{x_n}{x_0}\cdot Ay_0=\frac{x_n}{x_0}\cdot x_0=x_n$$

Since $A$ is continuous, we have that $\lim x_n=\lim (Ay_n)=A(\lim y_n)=Ay\in AK$. So, since any convergent sequence in $AK$ has its limit in $AK$ too, we conclude that $AK$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$. $\square$

---

I really love your example for where this fails for $\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2$. The reason why above proof does not work for higher dimensional co-domains is, that there is no such way to "lift" the sequence $x_n\in AK$ to the cone $K$ while preserving convergence, as we did above with

$$y_n:=y_0\cdot\frac{x_n}{x_0}.$$

Comment: Just to clarify,
(a) we can assume w.l.o.g that all $x_n$ are non-zero and have the same sign as we can essentially ignore the first few terms that could have different signs or be equal to zero, and only focus on the infinitely many $x_i$'s converging to a non-zero $x$ which would be non-zero and have the same signs? 
(b) would it better to say choose some non-zero $y_0$ such that $Ay_0 = x_0$ rather than using $A^{-1}$ as this does not exist? 
(c) there is no such example from $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: (a) Exactly. (b) $A^{-1}$ was not meant to denote the inverse map, but the pre-image map, which maps $x_0$ to the set $\{y\in \Bbb R^2\mid Ay=x_0\}$. That's why I wrote $\in$ there. But yes, maybe $Ay_0=x_0$ would be better. (c) Probably the proof works for all $n$, you are right. Thanks.

Comment: (b) Ah I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think there is a simpler reason for the nonexistence: $AK$ is a convex cone in $\mathbb R^1$ and there are only $4$ different convex cones in $\mathbb R^1$: $\{0\}$, $[0,\infty)$, $(-\infty,0]$ and $\mathbb R^1$. All of them are closed.

Comment: @gerw In fact, this is ridiculously simple. You should make an answer out of that. You would have my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

There cannot be a counterexample with $A \colon \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^1$:
$AK$
is a convex cone in $\mathbb R^1$ and there are only 4 different convex cones in $\mathbb R^1$: $\{0\}$, $[0,∞)$, $(−∞,0]$ and $\mathbb R^1$. All of them are closed.

Moreover, there cannot be a counterexample with $A \colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$: If $A$ has full rank, it is invertible and thus $AK$ is closed (it is the preimage of $K$ w.r.t. $A^{-1}$). If $A$ does not have full rank, the situation is essentially one-dimensional and the above objection applies.

Hence, the minimal counterexample has $A \colon \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$ and you have found it :)